# Not able to connect Tessera with Quorum node

Tags: quorum, ipc, constellation

I am following up with the Quorum set up as mentioned @ https://docs.goquorum.com/en/latest/Getting%20Started/Creating-A-Network-From-Scratch/#tessera 
I have created 3 Quorum nodes with RAFT consensus. Now I am trying to install the Privacy manager Tessera with them. I am able to generate the pub and private keys and run them successfully. However attaching the Tessera with quorum node is failing with the below error.

```
panic: MustNew: Failed to connect to Constellation (./new-node-1t/tm.ipc): Constellation Node API did not respond to upcheck request

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/private/constellation.MustNew(0xc00003600f, 0x14, 0xc00003600f)
    /home/srikant/Desktop/quorum-master/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/private/constellation/constellation.go:108 +0x190
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/private.FromEnvironmentOrNil(0x118e95e, 0xe, 0xc000225f48, 0x9ed863)
    /home/srikant/Desktop/quorum-master/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/private/private.go:20 +0x64
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/private.init.ializers()
    /home/srikant/Desktop/quorum-master/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/private/private.go:23 +0x36
```

Here is a snippet form my config,json file from Tessera.

```
{  "useWhiteList": true,
   "jdbc": {
       "username": "sa",
       "password": "",
       "url": "jdbc:h2:/home/srikant/Desktop/fromscratch/new-node-1t/db1;MODE=Oracle;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=0",
       "autoCreateTables": true
   },
   "serverConfigs":[
       {
           "app":"ThirdParty",
           "enabled": true,
           "serverAddress": "http://localhost:9081",
           "communicationType" : "REST"
       },
       {
           "app":"Q2T",
           "enabled": true,
            "serverAddress":"unix:/home/srikant/Desktop/fromscratch/new-node-1t/tm.ipc",
           "communicationType" : "REST"
       },
       {
           "app":"P2P",
           "enabled": true,
           "serverAddress":"http://localhost:9001",
           "sslConfig": {
               "tls": "OFF"
           },
           "communicationType" : "REST"
       }
   ],
   "peer": [
       {
           "url": "http://localhost:9001"
       },
       {
           "url": "http://localhost:9003"
       },
       {
           "url": "http://localhost:9005"
       }
   ],
   "keys": {
       "passwords": [],
       "keyData": [
           {
               "privateKeyPath": "/home/srikant/Desktop/fromscratch/new-node-1t/new-node-1.key",
               "publicKeyPath": "/home/srikant/Desktop/fromscratch/new-node-1t/new-node-1.pub"
           }
       ]
   },
   "alwaysSendTo": []
}
```

The Path of tm.ipc file in the reference is correct. However its failing with the following command.

```
PRIVATE_CONFIG=./new-node-1t/tm.ipc nohup geth --datadir new-node-1 --nodiscover --verbosity 5 --networkid 31337 --raft --raftport 50000 --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 22000 --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3,quorum,raft --emitcheckpoints --port 21000
```

Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: You should check tessera log to see what the issue is. It likely has failed to come up. One common issue is that if you fetched the built tessera, then itd need Java 8.

Comment: The Tessera node is working fine. and Yes I have picked out the built jar and ran it via java 8. http://localhost:9081 actually returns I'm up in the browser. The problem is with the Tessera while connecting with the Quorum node

Comment: Probably best to follow up on our slack as I suspect its a misconfig somewhere. Our slack: https://bit.ly/quorum-slack